# Include a php library and cant access it from another php page

Tags: php, parsing, rss, simplepie

Im loading the php rss parsing library [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) onto my site and i include it in the header.php file like so:

```
<?php
    // Make sure that SimplePie is loaded
require_once('inc/simplepie.inc');
$feed = new SimplePie('rss.com'); <-- This is a example url

// Make sure the content is being served out to the browser properly.
$feed->handle_content_type();

?>
```

Then i try to access the object from another page called page.php and it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_items() on a non-object in /home/callofdu/public_html/wp-content/themes/Starkers/page.php on line 13
```

I get the error from this line of code:

```
<?php
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{}
?>
```

Its weird because if i include both of those chuncks of code together on the same php page it all works fine.

I just am not understanding something, please help.

Comment: Sounds like the $feed object is not getting populated when you initiate the object. Make sure that the url you are passing is an actual feed.

Comment: like i said in the question, when i include everything on one page it works fine. when i seperate them into different php files it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Are you opening `page.php` in a separate request? (i.e. by manually surfing to `[...]/page.php`? As soon as one script is finished, you lose all variables, so also `$feed`.

Comment: i have an index.php file that is calling header.php, page.php, footer.php.

should i require the simplie library in the index.php file and it should stay there?

Comment: So i was able to solve my problem by making a functions.php file and just calling all the code when i needed it, including loading simplepie each time the function was called. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things could be wrong here:

1. Code order is incorrect.
   Realise that when you `require` or `include` a PHP file, the entire code of that file will be executed *at that point*. In other words: interpret the command `require_once` as "Insert file contents here", and check whether the order of lines of code are still right.
2. You are calling page.php in a separate request.
   If you use your browser to manually surf to page.php after the completeion of the previous page, `$feed` will no longer exist. If you do want it to live on between requests, do the following:

   a. Replace all instances of `$feed` with `$_SESSION['feed']`
   b. In the first line of every file that you surf to (so not the require'd files), put `session_start();`

Comment: there is a function called insert_file_contents()?

Comment: No, Sorry, what I mean is: `require` means exactly that.

Comment: So the only way to include a php library so every page on my site can access it, i have to use the session variable that you explained?

Answer (score 2):

The require and include calls in php basically take the contents of that file and slap in place.

So if you follow the linear path that php taking while running a script, you have to make sure that the library is called before you use it.

Basically in practice, if you are executing page.php as a standalone then you will need to require it in that script also, however, if page.php is being included in the first script you mentioned then you don't need to require it again, but make sure the library is included before page.php

ie

```
<?php
    // Make sure that SimplePie is loaded
require_once('inc/simplepie.inc');
$feed = new SimplePie('rss.com');

// Make sure the content is being served out to the browser properly.
$feed->handle_content_type();


require_once "page.php";
?>
```

doesn't need to be required in both

As for the differences between the require and include calls check out
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

EDIT:
After seeing this is Wordpress related, remember variable scoop. Variables do not inherent from a functions parent. So in page.php try:

```
<?php
global $feed;

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{}
?>
```

Comment: i tried it the global in the header.php and then in the page.php file and that didnt get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the libraries on EVERY page you're using the library's functions.

Comment: the header.php file is called on every single page on my website

Comment: im using wordpress and it builts the webpage by calling header.php then page.php(or loop.php) then footer.php

Answer (score 0):

I think it is relative paths issue. Try using absolute paths. Or check if path to `rss.com` is okay. May be you need to call it in another way: `$feed = new SimplePie('../rss.com');`

Comment: Very unlikely, if you require an external file, that doesn't change your CWD, and TS has everything working when all code is in 1 file. Also, requiring a file that does not exist results in a Fatal error being thrown.

Comment: Place `var_dump($feed);` before `foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)`. If it prints some value that is not SimplePie object, thah you may be redefining this variable somewhere. If it prints NULL, than you must think about scope of variable - it may be defined in local scope of some function. Also, you may place `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` to see if there are some other errors.